# Does the square function map from a field to a group on real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The square map $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x^2$ should preserve multiplication but not addition on the field $(\mathbb{R},+,\times)$. Does this mean it maps from a field to a group? My confusion may come from the notation $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I learned from comments so far that the answer is basically no. A morphism must map to structure of the same type I now remember too. But can we confirm this is a morphism from $(\mathbb{R}-0,\times)$ to itself? Should we infer structure (if any) by context if we see something like $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Would $f: (\mathbb{R}-0,\times) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}-0,\times)$ be appropriate notation?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is not a group under multiplication as $0$ has no inverse.  If you restrict your map to the non-zero reals then, yes, squaring is a map from the abelian group $\mathbb R^*$ to itself (the same would be true for any abelian group).

Comment: The question expressed by the title is different from that asked in the body of the Question.   There are many fields where the square map is an isomorphism,  but the real numbers are not an example of that.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should have written $\mathbb{R}-0$. But in the field $(\mathbb{R},+,\times)$ I believe that the $-0$ is part of the definition. So does $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mean $(\mathbb{R},+,\times) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\times)$? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: So based on hardmath's comment, when I see $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I should assume the structure is not the real number field but rather a mutliplicative group on the real numbers in both domain and codomain?

Comment: The arrow notation here does not say anything about the structure. It's purely set-related.

Comment: We can't guess what was intended by the notation.  Perhaps the writer was simply intending the polynomial map from $\mathbb R$ to itself.

Comment: It's a map, not a morphism.

Comment: OK, thank you Robert, I think that makes sense to me. It is not a morphism on the field because it does not preserve addition, right? But wouldn't it be a morphism on group $(\mathbb{R}-0,\times)$? And in general, should we determine structure (if any) by context when we see $R \rightarrow R$?